# Three Circle Object is not rotate 360degree

Tags: html, css, css-animations

> Please see the code below.

```css
.nk-loader-c {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nk-loader-circle {
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  animation: obj-rotate 3s linear infinite;
  height: 36px;
}

.obj-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #6540eb;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: obj-grow 1.5s linear infinite;
  margin: -5px;
}

.obj-circle:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #3766f3;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.obj-circle:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #603aef;
  animation-delay: .75s;
}

.obj-circle:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #2998f6;
  animation-delay: .37s;
}

@keyframes obj-rotate {
  to{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


@keyframes obj-grow {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nk-loader-c">
  <div class="nk-loader-circle">
    <div class="obj-circle"></div>
    <div class="obj-circle"></div>
    <div class="obj-circle"></div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

> Can anyone help me with this? the rotation of the object circle is not
> really 360degrees. Can anyone help me how can I make the rotation
> 360deg?
> But when I tried using two circles the rotation if working on 360degress.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```css
.nk-loader-c {
padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nk-loader-circle {
position:absolute;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  animation: obj-rotate 3s linear infinite;
  height: 36px;
}

.obj-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #6540eb;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: obj-grow 1.5s linear infinite;
  margin: -5px;
}

.nk-loader-circle:nth-child(1){
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

.nk-loader-circle:nth-child(1) .obj-circle{
  background-color: #3766f3;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.nk-loader-circle:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: -.25s;
}

.nk-loader-circle:nth-child(2) .obj-circle{
  background-color: #603aef;
  animation-delay: .75s;
}

.nk-loader-circle:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.nk-loader-circle:nth-child(3) .obj-circle{
  background-color: #2998f6;
  animation-delay: .37s;
}

@keyframes obj-rotate {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes obj-grow {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nk-loader-c">
  <div class="nk-loader-circle">
    <div class="obj-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nk-loader-circle">
    <div class="obj-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nk-loader-circle">
    <div class="obj-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```